# Network file sharing with Apple Filing Protocol (AFP)

Tags: apple

How can I share files over the network, between an Ubuntu system (client side) and a macOS system (server side) using Apple Filing Protocol (AFP)?

Comment: This is more appropriate on askubuntu http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: you might want to ask this question here: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: `apt-get install netatalk` [This page](http://anders.com/projects/netatalk/) appears to be a tolerable enough guide.

Answer (score 3):

No, people, you've got it backwards. He wants a client, not server.

Check this one out: http://sites.google.com/site/alexthepuffin/home

Answer (score 2):

**AFPCMD**  (Ubuntu as Client)

AFPCMD is a command-line tool to help transfer  files  to  and  from  a server  using  Apple Filing Protocol (AFP).  This is typically either Netatalk, Mac OS or MacOS X.

This can be done as a non-root user. It offers  either  an  interactive command-line (like a traditional FTP client) or for batch retrievals.

More info at: [Ubuntu Manuals - AFPCMD](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/afpcmd.1.html)

**AFPFS-NG**  (Ubuntu as Client)

AFPFS-NG is an Apple Filing Protocol client that will allow BSD, Linux and Mac OS X systems to access files exported from a Mac OS system with AFP over TCP.

More info at: [AFPFS-NG Home](https://sites.google.com/site/alexthepuffin/home)

**Netatalk**  (Mac as Client - switching sides)

Netatalk is a freely-available Open Source AFP fileserver. A UNIX, Linux or BSD system running Netatalk is capable of serving many Macintosh clients simultaneously as an AppleShare file server (AFP).

To install it from terminal use `apt-get install netatalk`. It's also available from Ubuntu Software Center.

More info at: [Netatalk Home](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/)